# Mutt- Could not connect to smtp.gmail.com (network is unreachable)

Tags: mutt

im trying to use mutt to send an email with one attachment, and i keep getting the error
`could not connect to smtp.gmail.com (Network is unreachable).`
one thing to note is that one week ago i tried to send email with the exact settings on my muttrc file and it worked fine.
Im on debian 9.

my ~/.muttrc setting are

```
set realname = "my name"

set from = "user@gmail.com"
set use_from = yes
set envelope_from = yes

set smtp_url = "smtps:// user@gmail.com@smtp.gmail.com:465/"
set smtp_pass = "mypassword"
set imap_user = "user@gmail.com"
set imap_pass = "mypassword"
set folder = "imaps://imap.gmail.com:933"
set spoolfile = "+INBOX"
set ssl_starttls = yes
set ssl_force_tls = yes

bind index G imap-getch-mail
set editor = "vim"
set charset = "utf-8"
set record = ''
```

also i read online that google sometimes becomes unreachable or something like that, if that were the case i would like someone to tell me how can i tell when this is the case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To investigate this:

First check if the remote host is reachable with `ping`:

```
$ ping smtp.gmail.com
PING gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com (108.177.15.109) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from wr-in-f109.1e100.net (108.177.15.109): icmp_seq=1 ttl=35 time=39.6 ms
```

Ok.

Then check if it can be reached on port 465 :

```
$ telnet smtp.gmail.com 465
Trying 108.177.15.109...
(no response)
```

There a several possible reasons why port 465 cannot be reached:

- a firewall prevents port 465 from going through
- the port number is incorrect

Comment: i´ve done both these steps, i get a normal response from the ping but i get no response when i try to telnet port 465 or port 587. What is confusing me is that 1 week ago this ran fine and im pretty sure that nothing in my network changed.Do you have any tips of things i could try to find a resolution

Comment: ok ive looked around and i think that something happened with the ports that my pc has open, how would i open port 465 ,587 and 993

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when working on Zammad Helpdesk and Ticketing System.

The issue was that I had a security policy on my server on Amazon Web Services that blocked/refused the Application to send requests to ports that are not allowed on the server.

So since ports `993` for `imap.gmail.com`, `995` for `pop.gmail.com` and `465` or `587` for `smtp.gmail.com` are not allowed on by the security policy on the server, connections to them will not be permitted, which led to the issue:

> Host not reachable!

I resolved it by simply opening the ports/allowing connections requests to those ports on the server's security policy.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**.